# RxSwift: disposed(by:) weirdness

Tags: swift, rx-swift

So the code below compiles with the errror

```
var doneSubscription: Disposable = item.doneSubjectObservable
        .debug("doneSubscriptions")
        .subscribe(
            onNext: {
                done in self.validateDone(done: done, item: item)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

> Value of type '()' does not conform to specified type 'Disposable' 
>   on the line .disposed(by: disposeBag)

But I can do this without error:

```
var doneSubscription: Disposable = item.doneSubjectObservable
        .debug("doneSubscriptions")
        .subscribe(
            onNext: {
                done in self.validateDone(done: done, item: item)
        })

    doneSubscription.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

All I've done is moved `.disposed(by: disposeBag)` out of the subscription chain.

Am I missing something, aren't these two approaches equivalent?

Answer (score 5):

No, they are not equivalent.

In the first case, you are storing the return value of this whole expression into `doneSubscription`, a variable of type `Disposable`:

```
item.doneSubjectObservable
    .debug("doneSubscriptions")
    .subscribe(
        onNext: {
            done in self.validateDone(done: done, item: item)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Since `disposed(by:)` does not return anything, this gives you an error.
In the second case however, you actually assigned a `Disposable` to the variable `doneSubscription` - the return value of `subscribe`.

To fix your first case, simply remove the variable declaration.

Comment: Simple yet perfect explanation :) Hence +1